# How to implement a drop down multiselect in HTML flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I would like to implement something similar to what we find in stack overflow. When we type something , we get a drop down of matching texts and then we can select the required option. And then add more tags until we decide to click on submit.

The selected tags, I will try retrieve as a list in my .py file.

Please help. So far I can only implement a multiselect.

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried?

Comment: [This](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) php tutorial might be useful for the frontend.